# JAXB Element Wrapper for a Single Group of Elements When Marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I wish to have an XML structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MSG>
   <CASE>
       <Field1></Field1>
       <Field2></Field2>
   </CASE>
</MSG>
```

The problem is, with the @XmlElementWrapper, I need a collection of items but there will be only 1 case item. How can I have multiple root elements, for a single collection of elements? Preferably in a single class.

I want something like this, but it throws an exception.

```
@XmlRootElement( name="MSG")
public class XMLStructure {

   @XmlElementWrapper(name="CASE")
   @XmlElement(name = "Field1")
   private String field1;

   @XmlElementWrapper(name="CASE")
   @XmlElement(name = "Field2")
   private String field2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation of [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) we have an `@XmlPath` extension that enables you to map this as:

```
@XmlRootElement( name="MSG")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XMLStructure {

   @XmlPath("CASE/Field1/text()")
   private String field1;

   @XmlPath("CASE/Field2/text()")
   private String field2;
}
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about the `@XmlPath` extension on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: Does the @XmlAccessorType have to be XmlAccessType.FIELD)? Because one field is calculated when I call the getter but when I change t @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY), it throws an exception saying a Duplicate Property has been found

Comment: @Codemiester - You are correct (and I have updated my answer).  If you annotate fields you should also annotate the class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.